# react-datepicker "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation"

Tags: javascript, css, html, reactjs, react-datepicker

I'm implementing [react-datepicker](https://github.com/Hacker0x01/react-datepicker) with portal mode. It works good on browser but following error happens on mobile(browser mobile mode).

> Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener invocation

After some researching, I've applied `touch-action: none;` css to my calendar css and it doesn't help me.

For now, it doesn't prevent event of calendar's outside on mobile.
You can test it from their [demo site](https://reactdatepicker.com/) - Portal Version.
Please make sure that run site by mobile mode in browser.

How can I remove this error?

Answer (score -3):

is there something infront of prevent default. either a e. or event. If so have you defined that inside the function, very new to react but seems like a problem I've had in Jquery/Javascript.